# Can we share memory between workers in a Pytorch DataLoader?

Tags: pytorch

My dataset depends on a 3GB tensor. This tensor could either be on the CPU or the GPU. The bottleneck of my code is the data loading preprocessing. But I can't add more than a few workers without killing my RAM.

This sounds silly for me: why could each worker receives a copy of the 3GB tensor, when this one is exactly the same across each worker?

Is there any solution for letting the workers access to a single version of this tensor?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The Pytorch [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#multi-process-data-loading) explicitly mentions this issue with `DataLoader` duplicating the underlying dataset (at least on Windows and macOS as I understand).

In general, you should not eagerly load all your dataset in memory because of such issue. The dataset should be lazy loaded, i.e. samples should only be loaded when they are accessed in the `__getitem__` method.

If your whole dataset in stored on disk as a monolithic tensor, you could fragment it into individual samples and save them into a folder for instance.

You could then define your dataset as:

```py
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from glob import glob
from os.path import abspath


class MyDataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, folder: str):
    # Retrieve all tensor file names
    folder = abspath(folder)
    self.files = glob(f"{folder}/*.pt")

  def __getitem__(self, index: int):
    # Load tensors on demand
    return torch.load(self.files[index])
 
  def __len__(self) -> int:
    return len(self.files)
```

---

Another solution is to memory-map the dataset. This is what HuggingFace does for huge datasets, take a look [here](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter5/4?fw=pt#the-magic-of-memory-mapping). This avoids loading the whole dataset in RAM and also allows it to be shared in multiple processes without copies.

Answer (score 0):

Ray may be an interesting option for you. Check out [ray training datasets](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-air/check-ingest.html#air-ingest)!

Additionally, you could also use

```
data_id = ray.put(data)
```

to dump your data, and

```
data = ray.get(data_id)
```

to load the same files without copying them between functions.